# How to factory reset Ubuntu Core 18

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, reset

I am looking to use Ubuntu Core 18 as the OS for a Raspberry Pi IoT device.

Looking to have a factory reset function in case the thing does screwy.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Is it possible to have a snap that removes all other snaps but the main ones and re-install them?

Thanks!

Comment: Fair, I was hoping for a way with Ubuntu core to be able to revert to an earlier state.

Comment: You can revert Ubuntu Core to the previous version (but not your initially-installed version if it's more than a few versions ago). That's a fundamental part of the Ubuntu Core design. If an update goes wonky and a snap (including Ubuntu) fails to start, the older version will start instead.

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset is a feature that will come with Ubuntu Core 20 ...

If you run on a Pi I'd just flash the SD freshly with a new image though, thats surely the quickest way to go back to factory state ...